# return IEnumerable<ProductCategory> MongoDB.Driver

Tags: c#, mongodb

Please, tell me how to get all data from product category Mongo table and return data as IEnumerable.
Thank you in advance!

```
public class CategoryService<ProductCategory> : EntityService<ProductCategory> 
                                                where ProductCategory: IMongoEntity
{
    public IEnumerable<ProductCategory> getAllCategories()
    {
        var collection = this.MongoConnectionHanler
                             .MongoCollection
                             .Find<ProductCategory>("productcategory");

        return collection.XXX;
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot convert the result to AsQueryble and after that to peform a second convertion to IEnumerable.

Comment: public class CategoryService<ProductCategory>: EntityService<ProductCategory> where ProductCategory: IMongoEntity
    {
        public IEnumerable<ProductCategory> getAllCategories()
        {
            var collection = this.MongoConnectionHanler.MongoCollection.Find("productcategory").ToListAsync();
            IEnumerable<ProductCategory> coll = (IEnumerable<ProductCategory>)collection;
            return coll;
        }
    }

Comment: what version of the driver are you using?